# Adding custom Single-Block symmetric Cipher in 3.9.11 kernel's crypto API

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptography, cryptoapi, ipsec

I have developed a Single-Block symmetric Cipher [CIPHER] Algorithm for IPsec in kernel[3.9.11]'s crypto API. After loading the .ko module into the kernel I can see my algorithm's information provided in /proc/crypto.

Now the problem comes when I want to establish an IPsec tunnel between two linux machines and I get the error

```
"tun/1x1": requested kernel enc ealg_id=254 not present
```

When I searched the code to pinpoint the problem, found out that there is a function `xfrm_probe_algs` that its functionality is to check the availability of crypto algorithms. In this function the line

```
status = crypto_has_ablkcipher(ealg_list[i].name, 0, 0);
```

seems to check for "Asynchronous multi-block ciphers" only. However, the algorithm that I have written is of the type "Single-Block symmetric Cipher" And because of this problem my algorithm does not work properly. I would like to know is there any way that I can use my single-block symmetric cipher in IPsec tunnels in 3.9.11 kernel or not.

Best Regards